# Install Chocolatey package if not installed with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, chocolatey

I'm not an expert with Ansible and I'm trying to install a chocolatey package via Ansible only if not present. I'm trying to achieve this by using the facts from chocolatey to determine if Git is installed. If Git is not present in facts, run the task to install it:

```
- name: Gather facts from chocolatey
  win_chocolatey_facts:

- name: Install git
  win_chocolatey:
    name: git.install
  when: ansible_chocolatey['packages'] != "git.install"
```

This is the output from chocolatey facts, where I can see the packages currently installed on my machine:

```
"ansible_facts": {
            "ansible_chocolatey": {
                 "config": {
                     ......
                  },
                 "feature": {
                      ....
                  },
                  "outdated": [
                      {
                         .....
                      },
                 ],
                  "packages": [
                      {
                          "package": "chocolatey-compatibility.extension",
                          "version": "1.0.0"
                      },
                      {
                          "package": "chocolatey-core.extension",
                          "version": "1.4.0"
                      },
                      {
                          "package": "chocolatey-dotnetfx.extension",
                          "version": "1.0.1"
                      },
                      {
                          "package": "ruby",
                          "version": "3.1.3.1"
                      },
                      .....
                      .....
```

The error I get is:

```
fatal: [ip-x.x.x.x.eu-west-2.compute.internal]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_chocolatey['packages'] != "git.install"' failed. 
The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_chocolatey['packages'] != "git.install" is undefined\n\n...
```

Can I please have some help to achieve this?

I'm expecting to install Git package if not present on one machine and skip this task if Git is already installed

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to "check" if the package is present, as Ansible, via the collection, will do that for you.

An example would be:

```
- name: Install git
  win_chocolatey:
    name: git.install
    version: '2.39.2'
    state: present
```

The important part here being `state: present`, which based on the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/chocolatey/chocolatey/win_chocolatey_module.html#parameters):

> When present, will ensure the package is installed.

If you haven't already seen, the Chocolatey Community Repository provides examples on how to install packages via Chocolatey:

https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/git.install#ansible

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ansible is [idempotent](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html), meaning it will only make a change if it needs to make a change. For example, you can tell Ansible "ensure this package is installed" and it will install it (reporting "changed") if it is not currently installed or skip over it (reporting "ok") if the package is already installed.

This means you only need to specify the install task:

```
- name: Install git
  win_chocolatey:
    name: git.install
    state: present
```

The important thing here is the `state`, by stating `present` (which is the default) you're saying "make sure A version of this is installed, but I don't care which."

You could also set it to `latest` which says "install the latest version, and if the latest version is already installed, do nothing."

Comment: `Ansible is idempotent` => Idempotence is a strong concept in ansible and you should make sure that your playbooks are following that rule, by properly testing them with a tool like molecule which has a specific test for that, and by using adequate `changed_when` stanza on your tasks when relevant. Most modules distributed by ansible or the ansible community are idempotent out of the box. `win_chocolatey` (seems to be... I never used it) one of them. A dummy example of a non idempotent task out of the box: `- shell: echo toto > somefile.txt`